# Criteria for a Regular Singular Point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My book on differential equations says that $x_{0}$ is a regular singular point of the differential equation $P(x)y'' + Q(x)y' + R(x)y = 0$ if $(x - x_{0})\frac{Q}{P}$ and $(x - x_{0})^{2}\frac{R}{P}$ have convergent Taylor series about $x_{0}$. This criteria seems tedious to check because it means I have to expand $\frac{Q}{P}$ and $\frac{R}{P}$ as Taylor series, etc. Is there an easier way to check if a point is regular singular?

Comment: Seen [this](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Regular_singular_point#Examples_for_second_order_differential_equations)? The idea is to check for poles...